# PHP upload not working

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I've been trying to get my PHP upload script working, the HTML side seems to work but the PHP keeps returning a failed result.  I am using iPage hosting.  Here is my script:

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['userfile'])){
$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo "<p>";

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
  echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
   echo "Upload failed";
}

echo "</p>";
echo '<pre>';
echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);
print "</pre>";
} else {
?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="512000" />
    Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Check if the folder is writeable. If it is, then try a relative path instead of what you're using now. I.e.: `$uploaddir = 'uploads/';`

Comment: Thanks Fred.  Needed to do both to get it working :)

Comment: If you want the question closed, I can make it as an answer, it's up to you.

Comment: As per your request, it has been done. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment to answer to close the question, since that's what the issue was, *both*.

Check to see if the folder is writeable. If it is, then try a relative path instead of what you're using now.

I.e.: `$uploaddir = 'uploads/';`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the upload directory has the correct permissions - ***Writable and Proper Owner***

You will run into issues when the file size is over 512000, you should check the size of the file using the $_FILE array and return an error message. Just a suggestion as you have already closed this.

```
    // Error Checking Extended
    if($_FILES['userfile']['error'] == 2) {
       echo "You've exceeded the maximum file upload size of 512kb.";
       return false;
    }
```